# What happens when you register Android API < 8 to C2DM?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

What happens when you try to register for C2DM an Android device with API level lower than 8? Will it crash the app or fail silently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just get action `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` with not empty string extra `error`. I'm not sure, but think there will be `PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR` value.